# UITableViewRowAction text not centered

Tags: ios, uitableview

To make my `UITableViewRowAction` buttons equal widths, I've added white space around the title's for the shorter ones. So I made my edit action like this:

```
let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "  Edit  ", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
})
```

However, it looks like the title isn't being properly centered horizontally. Here is a picture:

[image: pic]

Can anybody help me understand how I would make it so the title is centered?

Comment: I think that with the standard UItableViewCell you can´t do this, sadly, are you willing to use a third party library to do this?

Comment: Actually, changing the title from `"  Edit  "` to `"Edit    "` seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Well then congrats, you find it!, anyway is weird ;) lol

Comment: I'd dig in to see why it works like that but I'll probably get lost haha